# How to Pass env variable to a shell script within Makefile rule

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sqoop

I have a rule within a Makefile which tries to render some text with env variables, I always get this variable empty whenever I pass it to the $(shell ) command

the following is the Makefile I am trying to pass the env variables with
and I am using sqoop to fetch data from sql server running a query with defined date in where statement

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

ifndef DATE
override DATE=$(shell date --date="1 day ago" +%Y%m%d)
endif

test:
        sqoop --target-dir /tmp/output/ --fields-terminated-by '\t' --split-by id --query '$(shell cat query.sql | env DATE=$(DATE) python -m mypackage.render)'
```

I run commands like `make test DATE=20190728`

when I pass the env argument like `| env DATE=20190728 python -m mypackage.render` then I am able to see the query with `where convert(varchar,created_at,112) = '20190728'` but when I use env var I always get an empty string with the env variable like `where convert(varchar,created_at,112) = ''`

Comment: Please provide the actual command you run, and the output you "see".

Comment: @Jens I have edited the question to have more details about my approach and why I am using cat within shell, is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `make` $(shell ...) invocation. You probably want command substitution (a shell feature). And kill a useless cat.

```
test:
    $(MAKE) do_test VAR=test

do_test:
    VAR=$(VAR) python -m mypackage.render < file.txt
```

Note that it is not recommended to set `SHELL` in a Makefile.